# How to replace identical consecutive values from a 1D array efficiently

Tags: python, numpy

Surprisingly, after a fair bit of research, I did not find any post sparking a good idea to solve this simple problem.

I have a 1D `numpy` array of shape `(n, )` which is mostly zeros with a few other positive values.

```
D = np.zeros(10)
D[2] = 1
D[5] = 4
D[7] = 3

Out: array([0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 4., 0., 3., 0., 0.])
```

However, sometimes, one of the values (which is a trigger at the given sample) might be repeated during the next (or few next samples).

```
D = np.zeros(10)
D[2] = 1
D[3] = 1
D[5] = 4
D[7] = 3

Out: array([0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 4., 0., 3., 0., 0.])
```

In this case, I want to process the array to replace the identical consecutive values by 0; in this case, to replace the second `1` by `0`.

```
In: array([0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 4., 0., 3., 0., 0.])
Out: array([0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 4., 0., 3., 0., 0.])
```

For one additional complexity level, I would like to define a tolerance, and if every element right after a value `x>0` is close enough to `x`, then they get replaced by 0.

```
In: array([0., 0., 1., 0.98, 1.01, 4., 0., 3., 3.1, 0.]), tolerance = 0.05
Out: array([0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 4., 0., 3., 3.1, 0.])
```

This is fairly easy to do by looping on the array with either a `while` or a `for` loop. However, as this is for an online application, I was looking for a vectorized solution in numpy. If anyone has any suggestion, any function I could look at to do this as efficiently as possible, please comment!

Comment: `D[np.where(np.diff(D)==0)] = 0`

Comment: @not_speshal Thank you very much. Never seen `np.diff()` until now, and once adding the arg `preprend=[0]`, it works great. I should be able to adapt it for the tolerance case easily. Feel free to add this as an answer. Solution: `D[np.where(np.diff(D, prepend=[0]) <= tolerance)] = 0`

Comment: Yeah so the whole things would be something like `x = np.diff(D,prepend=0)` and 
`D[np.where((D!=0) & (np.abs(x)<0.05))] = 0`

Comment: @Mathieu I was just working on the tolerance but you beat me ;)

Comment: @obchardon Good catch. I forgot the abs(). `D[np.where(np.abs(np.diff(D, prepend=[0])) <= tolerance)] = 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `np.diff()` like so:

```
D[np.where(np.diff(D)==0)] = 0
```

Edit: Including OP's solution to include tolerance and prepend:

```
D[np.where(np.diff(D, prepend=[0])<=tolerance)] = 0
```

Edit 2: @obchardon's excellent suggestion to remove the unnecessary `np.where`:

```
D[abs(np.diff(D, prepend=[0]))<=tolerance] = 0
```

Comment: np.diff return an array of size `n-1`, so we need to use the `prepend` to avoid a shift.

Comment: @obchardon - Yes, OP already mentioned that in the comments under the question

Comment: There was no explanation. Also you can use a boolean index: `D[np.diff(D, prepend=[0])<=tol] = 0` so we get rid of the useless np.where.

Comment: @obchardon Indeed, even better!

Comment: ho and one last thing, we still need to take the absolute value :p if we replace `3.1` by `2.9` for example, then this value will be set to 0 at the moment.

Comment: Now that's perfect =)